# error on echo server in Wso2-Application server 5.3.0

Tags: echo, wso2-as

I have installed Wso2-Application server 5.3.0 on ubundo 14.0.
when i run echo web service try this service. then application will automatically logout when i am the service list page.

- login to portal
- go to service list page --> *"https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9443/carbon/service-mgt/index.jsp?region=region1&item=services_list_menu"*
- open try echo service --> *"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9763/services/echo?tryit"*
- now refresh the service list page --> *"https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9443/carbon/service-mgt/index.jsp?region=region1&item=services_list_menu"* will redirects to https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

Comment: I tried out the steps mentioned above but this is not reproducible.

Comment: Please share the java version you are using.